# Efficient way to draw line by line to a bitmap context

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, bitmap, core-graphics

I have an application which is drawing image data line by line as it comes in from the network. I want to show this updating process instead of just the final image.

My original code to draw this looks like the following:

```
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){

       for (int i=0;i<len; i = i+3)
        {
            float r = 1.0*byteData[i]/256;
            float g = 1.0*byteData[i+1]/256;
            float b = 1.0*byteData[i+2]/256;

            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myView->bitmapContext, r,g,b, 1.0f) ;
            CGContextFillRect (g_myView->bitmapContext, CGRectMake(y, x, 1.0f, 1.0f)) ;            

            x++;
        }
    });
```

This works fine but I discovered that removing dispatch_sync() makes the performance much better (from around 100-200ms to a small fraction of that). However without this call things will crash quickly due to some race condition, which is reasonable since I think the UI should always be updated from the main thread.

In order to improve the performance and keep things proper my strategy is to create a temporary bitmap context, write the entire line to that, and then safely write that bitmap to my main one at the end of the process.

The code looks like this:

```
        CGContextRef context = [myView createCustomBitmapContextWithSize: CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 1.0f)] ; 

        for (int i=0;i<len; i = i+3)
        {
            float r = 1.0*byteData[i]/256;
            float g = 1.0*byteData[i+1]/256;
            float b = 1.0*byteData[i+2]/256;

            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, r,g,b, 1.0f) ;
            CGContextFillRect (context, CGRectMake(y, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f)) ;  

            x++;
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(void){
            CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
            CGContextDrawImage(myView->bitmapContext, CGRectMake(0,x,1024.0f,1.0f), image);
        });
```

The first problem with this is that it doesn't render at all, so I am probably using the APIs incorrectly. But I checked that the call to CGBitmapContextCreateImage() near the end takes around ~100ms just by itself, so even if I get it to render this will not help performance much.

Can someone please help me understand a more appropriate way to do this updating process?

I think the way I am actually drawing to the screen may be relevant, so I'll show my drawRect: function as well.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ;

    CGImageRef myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext) ;

    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myImage) ;

    CGImageRelease(myImage) ;

}
```

Comment: By the way, most image formats are compressed considerably, rather than sending raw RGB byte data. If you send raw RGB data, recognize that the transmission will be much slower than a standard image download. You'll therefore likely sacrifice overall performance for the sake of watching the download as it arrives. If you have to do it this way, so be it, but be aware of the offsetting considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you're synchronously dispatching the updating of the UI back to the main loop. That means that the (presumably) background processing of the image data is going to have to wait.

Generally, I'd be suggesting to dispatch asynchronously (to avoid having the background process wait for UI update). But, in this case, you probably don't want to dispatch it asynchronously either (because you could end up with the main queue getting backed up with requests that are coming in faster than it can process them).

I'd suggest decoupling the redrawing of the image from the loop in which you're processing the downloaded data. There are two mechanisms by which you could achieve that, both of which entail making sure your background process does *not* dispatch anything to the main queue itself, but rather:

1. Update pixel buffer in background thread but configure `CADisplayLink` on main run loop that will update the UI. A display link is like a `NSTimer`, except that it's linked to updates of the UI.
2. Use dispatch source of type `DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD` that keeps track of how many pixels you've received, for example. Again, update pixel buffer in the background thread, having it perform a `dispatch_source_merge_data` to update this pixel count. Then you have a `dispatch_source_set_event_handler` on the main thread, listening to these merge events.

Both of these techniques let you do processing in a background thread, updating with UI with the greatest possible frequency, but not risking either slowing the background task down to the speed of the UI updates nor backlogging the main thread with UI update requests.

Obviously, make sure whatever objects you access from both threads are properly synchronized, though. You need to make sure that data being used by main thread is not being mutated by the background thread at the same time.